# Ubuntu does not follow the preseed file for network settings

Tags: preseed, kickstart, cobbler

I am trying to automate Ubuntu installations using Cobbler and preseed.

I referred to this officical sample seed file for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt

I only edited the network related part in this file and now this is my `sample.seed` file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7793361/

I did not edit anything else. My target machine has two NICs: `eth0` and `eth1`.
Only `eth1` is connected to cobbler server through a private network.

After booting the Ubuntu Mini ISO it asks me to manually select between `eth0` and `eth1` and also ask to manually configure ip, netmask and other details as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roeVD.jpg
However, I have already set all these settings in that preseed file.

I have set my seed file location correctly as `/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/sample.seed`.

For testing purpose I disabled the second NIC, and only enabled one NIC. Then I manually set the network information. Still Ubuntu tries to use DHCP and says "can not configure network" and halts. Same issue if I use kickstart instead of preseed.

Kindly help to troubleshoot this issue. How can I make Ubuntu to autoselect `eth1` and apply all other networking settings such as IP address, network mask, etc. automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is described in [bug 855921](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcfg/+bug/855921).

If you want to use any specific interface, e.g. `eth0`, just pass `netcfg/choose_interface=eth0` to the kernel as a boot option.