# Preseed static network configuration does not work

Tags: networking, preseed

## Question

Please suggest if there are mis-configurations or if the symptom is a known issue.

Saw the other articles and set netcfg/choose_interface=eth0 as the boot parameter.

- [Preseed doesn't automatically select network interface on Ubuntu 14.04; automated install needs human input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617558/preseed-doesnt-automatically-select-network-interface-on-ubuntu-14-04-automate)
- [Ubuntu does not follow the preseed file for network settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497609/ubuntu-does-not-follow-the-preseed-file-for-network-settings)

### Problem

Expected the static network and host/domain would be configured in the /etc/network/interfaces based on the setting in preseed file below. However, DHCP was configured.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Other configurations in preseed file such as user, disk partition, etc were configured as expected. The installer log shows preseedings.

```
/var/log/installer# grep preseed syslog
Jun 21 17:24:51 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=http://xxx.96.102.150/ks.cfg preseed/url=http://xxx.96.102.150/preseed.txt
Jun 21 17:24:51 kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=http://xxx.96.102.150/ks.cfg preseed/url=http://xxx.96.102.150/preseed.txt
Jun 21 17:24:58 preseed: successfully loaded preseed file from file:///preseed.cfg
Jun 21 17:25:20 preseed: successfully loaded preseed file from /var/spool/kickseed/parse/preseed.cfg
Jun 21 17:25:46 anna[8833]: DEBUG: retrieving network-preseed 1.62ubuntu1
Jun 21 17:26:01 main-menu[7701]: INFO: Menu item 'network-preseed' selected
Jun 21 17:26:01 preseed: successfully loaded preseed file from http://xxx.96.102.150/preseed.txt
Jun 21 17:26:01 main-menu[7701]: (process:12262): 2016-06-21 17:26:01 URL:http://xxx.96.102.150/preseed.txt [7089/7089] -> "/tmp/debconf-seed" [1]
Jun 21 07:36:37 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/07preseed
```

The /var/log/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat file has the information below.

```
Name: netcfg/get_domain
Template: netcfg/get_domain
Value: demo.local
Owners: netcfg
Flags: seen

Name: netcfg/get_ipaddress
Template: netcfg/get_ipaddress
Value: xxx.96.102.139
Owners: netcfg
Flags: seen

...
```

**Workaround**

Put the network configuration in kickstart.

```
network --bootproto=static --device=eth0 --hostname=myhost --ip=xxx.96.102.139 --netmask=255.255.255.192 --gateway=xxx.96.102.129 --nameserver=xxx.96.102.141
```

### Environment

```
Static hostname: kickseed
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
       Boot ID: 2e4cc092b21c429e9e0e0d1a3316cf5d
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
  Architecture: x86_64
```

### Kickstart

Using kickstart to set the installation menu language, keyboard.

### Configurations

**isolinux/isolinux.cfg**

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 1
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

**isoinux/txt.cfg**

```
default install
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
    append  initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=http://xxx.96.102.150/ks.cfg preseed/url=http://xxx.96.102.150/preseed.txt netcfg/choose_interface=eth0
```

**Preseed file**

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NETWORK
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
# netcfg/choose_interface=eth0 is set as the boot parameter.
#d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# If you prefer to configure the network manually, uncomment this line and
# the static network configuration below.
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true

# Disable that annoying WEP key dialog.
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

# Static network configuration.
# IPv4 example
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string xxx.96.102.139
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.192
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string xxx.96.102.129
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string xxx.96.102.141
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
# Hostname:
netcfg  netcfg/get_hostname string  myhost

# Domain name:
netcfg  netcfg/get_domain   string  demo.local

# If you want to force a hostname, regardless of what either the DHCP
# server returns or what the reverse DNS entry for the IP is, uncomment
# and adjust the following line.
d-i netcfg/hostname string myhost
```